# Eclipse (android) - automatically rebuild modified library when launching project that uses it

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library, build-dependencies

In my workspace I have an android library project and an android app that uses it. The problem is I have to manually rebuild the library after I make some modifications to it in order to enable the app to see the changes.

Can this be automatized? I'd like to change some class in the lib and then run the app without having to manually click "Build project" on the lib each time.

Answer (score 0):

Select your project in the Package Explorer then click Project -> Build Automatically.  It slows down eclipse a bit but whenever a change is made, the project builds automatically.

Comment: well thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it out but I was thinking about kind of setting up the dependency chain. I mean, I've done some changes to lib, and then want to run the app. Eclipse knows that app depends on lib and since lib has changed it rebuilds it before rebuilding the app. Can this be done in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking then.

Comment: I don't want the project to build automatically whenever a change is made. I want it to build automatically if a change has been made and **only when** I explicitly click Run on my app project.

Comment: I know if you use build scripts it builds the dependencies first.  I don't know if eclipse does this automatically from their tools.